# How to check if located link contains a tag with a given text?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver, webdriverwait

I need to check if located link contains `<span class="extra-light">` with a given text.
The way I locate the link:

```
ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@so-extra=\"x12fog\"]"))
```

How to make it?

Comment: Where is the link element and what is the tag and the text? Totally unclear. Can you share a link to that page or at least the XML of it with more explanations what is your goal?

Comment: @Prophet quite clear as for me. I found a link by xpath - the code line for that is in topic. Then I know there should be a `span` tag inside that link (tag `a`). That span tag has a `class="extra-light"` and it wraps a given text (for example `stackoverflow`). So I just try to detect if the link contains that span tag. Clear?

Comment: Still not clear: are you looking **only** for `a` tags containing those spans, or are you also looking for `a` tags not containing that span?

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus I'm looking only for `a` tags with attribute `so-extra="x12fog"` containing span with `class="extra-light"` which contains a given text.

Comment: So then locate those `span` tags, and their `a` ancestors (with that attribute). Easy, no drama.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findElements` method with XPath locator defining the desired element as following:

```java
if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@so-extra='x12fog']//span[@class='extra-light' and contains(.,'stackoverflow')]")).size()>0){
    System.out.println("Element found");
}
```

`findElements` method return a list of found matching elements. So, if there is such element the list will be non-empty (size>0), otherwise the returned list will be empty.

Comment: What is a `.` in `contains(.,'stackoverflow')`? And does the declaration structure like this `//a[@so-extra='x12fog']//span[@class='extra-light'` defines outer `a` and inner `span`?

Comment: the dot `.` here means `any` i.e. we are looking for any attribute (id, class, text, style...) to contain "stackoverflow"  value

Comment: yes, `a` is parent node and `span` is child node inside the parent

Comment: "i.e. we are looking for any attribute (id, class, text, style...) to contain "stackoverflow" value" - does it reflect the structure `<span class="extra-light">stackoverflow</span>`? i.e. the value `stackoverflow` doesn't relate to any attribute.

Comment: It does. It's the `text` attribute value.

Comment: You may use the following syntax as well `contains(text(),'stackoverflow')` instead the `contains(.,'stackoverflow')` and this will limit searching in text attributes only

Answer (score 1):

Try either of the `xpath`.

```
//a[.//span[@class='extra-light']]
```

Or

```
//a[.//span[@class='extra-light' and text()='stackoverflow']]
```

Or

```
//a[.//span[@class='extra-light' and contains(.,'stackoverflow')]]
```

---

Code should be

```
ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[.//span[@class='extra-light' and text()='stackoverflow']]"))
```

Or

```
ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[.//span[@class='extra-light' and contains(.,'stackoverflow')]]"))
```

or

```
ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[.//span[@class='extra-light']]"))
```